# js.erb outputs as text instead of js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Site works fine on localhost, but when uploaded to Heroku, the result of create.js.erb outputs as text, and to the address: site/supporters.js, no idea why.   the site is just one page with a supporters form, and when submitted, is supposed to render the form and the list of supporters on the page.

page:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    TEXT
  </div>
</div>
<br>


<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="home_form">
      <%= render "supporters/form" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" id="home_list">
    <br>
    <%= render 'supporters/show_supporters' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
class SupportersController < ApplicationController

  ...  
  def create
    @supporter = Supporter.new(supporter_params)
    @supporters = Supporter.all.order(created_at: :desc)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  ...
```

create.js

```
<% if @supporter.save %>
    $("#home_list").html("<%= j render 'show_supporters' %>")
    $("home_form").html("<%= j render 'form' %>")
<% else %>
    $("#home_form").html("<%= j render 'form', supporter: @supporter %>") 
    $('#build_error').remove();
    <% if @supporter.errors.any? %>
      var build_error = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='build_error'>";
      build_error += "You've got <%= pluralize(@supporter.errors.count, 'error') %>.";
      build_error +=   "<ul id='error_explanation'>";
      <% @supporter.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <% if msg === "Ip has already been taken" %>
            <% msg = "You've already posted your support.   Thanks!" %>
        <% end %>
        build_error += "<li><%= j msg %></li>";
      <% end %>
      build_error +=   "</ul>";
      build_error += "</div>";
      $(build_error).insertBefore( "#home_form" );
    <% end %>           
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem and what you're expecting? "the result of create.js.erb outputs as text" ?

Comment: it's on this page https://deadindustry-newnew-recruit.herokuapp.com/   ... when you submit to the form, it spits out the elements to be rendered as text

Answer (score 0):

How the browser interprets the content of the response from the server is dependant on (amongst others) the Content-Type header.

If memory serves me well: In this case, because the controller doesn't have any other formats than the js to respond with, it will respond with the js for html/text content type requests as well.

Try adding another format, like this: `format.any { render plain: 'Hello' }` after your `format.js`, to debug the issue.

If you see the 'Hello' string instead of your js, then it's due to missing Content-Type headers in your request.

I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, didn't help! :)   came up as same thing.